# MySQL не выбирает по дате

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql, sql

```
WHERE DateAdd 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE ('2010-05-05','%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE ('2010-05-07','%Y-%m-%d')"
```

Выводит только записи 2010-05-05 и 2010-05-06, а **2010-05-07 - нет**, хоть эта запись есть,
и так с любой датой, нужно в конце +1 день добавлять, что бы выборка работала корректно.

Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: Какой тип данных используется для хранения даты?

Зачем вы используете STR_TO_DATE?

Comment: Я через PHP вставляю туда дату, Строковую информацию передаю в дату, что бы произвести выборку между датами.

Comment: @Юра Сучко, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так пробовали?

```
WHERE DateAdd 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE ('2010-05-05 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND  STR_TO_DATE ('2010-05-07 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')"
```

Comment: тот же результат.

Comment: @Юра Сучко, если у Вас хранимый тип __timestamp__, то вы должны учитывать и то, что он хранит в себе еще время. Поэтому вторая часть должна идти как конец дня "2010-05-07 23:59:59"(а у вас самое начало, полночь "2010-05-07 00:00:00").

Comment: упс, перепутал, конец дня если поставить:
WHERE DateAdd BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE ('2010-05-05 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE ('2010-05-07 23:59:59','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')"

Comment: Точно, спасибо.